# How to call tempfile.mkstemp() with "with"? - or why doesn't it return an fd with __exit__()?

Tags: python, with-statement, temporary-files, python-internals

To me the most idiomatic way of calling `tempfile.mkstemp()` would be as:

```
with tempfile.mkstemp() as fd, filename:
    pass
```

however, this obviously(?) raises `AttributeError: __exit__`

Calling `os.close(fd)` explicitly using try-finally is an easy way to solve this, but feels like violation of **There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.**

Is there a way to "fix" this in `tempfile` or is there a rationale why this has been implemented this way?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, please do comment how to improve the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `tempfile` module there are other, better suited ways to create a temporary file, such as [`TemporaryFile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) and others.

Especially, if you don't want the file to be deleted, use [`NamedTemporaryFile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), giving it the `delete=False` argument.

Answer (score 7):

The workings of the `with` statement is defined in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), including its so called *context management protocol*:

> This PEP proposes that the protocol consisting of the **enter**()
>       and **exit**() methods be known as the "context management protocol",
>       and that objects that implement that protocol be known as "context
>       managers".

`mkstemp` does not return a context manager, that is an object which implements the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, and is therefore not compatible.

An obvious workaround is to create a wrapper class that implements the context manager protocol.